# how to do Unicenta Magento 2 integration

Tags: magento2

Can anyone help me to integrate unicenta pos application with Magento 2 ? I have installed Magento 2 , where should I get unicenta Magento 2 plugin to start integration?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the exact same, however, with no luck... so far.!

Comment: Yes. So far no search results also.